# RTW ticket - complicated visa/passport issue

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, south-africa, sri-lanka, new-zealand-citizens

my family is travelling on a One World RTW trip which includes South Africa and Sri Lanka. Because we have both British and NZ passports and South Africa only has a visa waiver for British we booked our tickets on our British passports.

We now need to get long stay visas for Sri Lanka as we are travelling there for longer than 30 days. And it turns out it is much cheaper to get a visa for NZ passport holders than British!

Question is - can we show our NZ passports on arrival in Sri Lanka but leave on our British passports? Or is there another option I haven't thought of?

We once got stung by Air NZ when we were travelling on our British passports but our ESTAs for transit in the US were in our NZ passports and they removed us (including two small children) and our baggage from the flight until we could gain ESTAs on our British passports. So I am very sensitive about this!

Any help welcome thanks

Comment: Air NZ's behavior about your ESTAs appears to be incorrect?

Comment: Adding an RTW trip specific comment: a) you can (and should) choose the best/easiest passport for each country. b) it doesn't need to be the same passport that's in the booking, c) make sure you enter and leave a country on the same passport. d) tell the airline during check in that you are switching passports (if you do). For example: you leave Sri Lanka on your NZ passport and enter South Africa on your British passport